# Creating a Ruby gem with JavaScript files (Rails 3)

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I'm planing to create a simple Ruby gem. The functionality is depending on some `.js` files. My plan is to install the gem via Github.

My questions are:

1. should I write a generator to copy the js files?
2. what is the best place to keep the js files (is it vendor/assets/javascripts?)
3. how to write test cases for this (rspec2) ?

I'm using Rails > 3, Ruby 1.9.x and Ruby 2.x.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily use Javascripts library in ruby in following way -

1) We can put all js libararies in Vendor section and for their use
    we can define then application.js in following way

//= require datatable-pagination
.
.

2) Next if you want to use your own javascript then u put them into
    your assets folder and use then application.js in above way.

3) And if you want to make your own js library, then you can put
    your js libarary in lin folder.

Comment: Hi @amit, thanks for the answer, I want to do the same via a ruby gem. instead of manually copying the js files around